# Removing one blank page between two chapters

Tags: page-breaking

How can I remove one of the blank page between two chapters.

```
     \documentclass[12pt,titlepage,a4paper]{book}

     \input{chapter1}
     \newcommand*\NewPage{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null} 
     \NewPage
     \input{chapter2}
```

Comment: What is the `document class (+ options)`? Do you have any layout package loaded? How many blank pages do you have between chapters?

Comment: what is the intention of the `\NewPage` command (which looks wrong) Please always provide a _complete_  small document that shows the problem.

Comment: The document class is : \documentclass[12pt,titlepage,a4paper]{book}, In this way that I create new command I have two blank pages.

Comment: Of course you get two, because of `\null` that makes the current page non empty; but you don't need `\NewPage`, because `\chapter` issues `\cleardoublepage`, so the beginning of `chapter2.tex` will already insert a blank page if needed, and just one.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting

```
 \newcommand*\NewPage{\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null} 
 \NewPage
```

Should have the desired effect (the definition leaving `\null` at the top of the following page seems to be incorrect in all cases, and certainly is not wanted before a chapter heading)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a big table inside the page then you most probably get a blank space before the table start. Use `longtable` instead of `tabular` or `table` environment.